How to speed up the lemmatization of a Serie in a Python Dataframe
I got this line that lemmatize a serie of a pandas DataFrame in python.
 res = serie.parallel_apply(lambda x :' '.join([d.lemma_ for d in self.nlp_spacy(x)]))
I got 200 000 rows of datas in this dataframe and other treatment on this serie are made. And all of these treatement are very long. Is there a way to speed up this specific treatment.
I heard that vectorized operations are faster with DataFrame. Is there a way to do like this ? The apply method is also very long because it checks all the values. How can i avoid using it ?

Vectorization mainly applies for native types and functions provided by the target library (integer, floating-point numbers and some kind of strings), but not much objects (of an external module). Actually, some vectorized operation can be applied on columns with objects but it will often not be significantly faster.

I found a way to speed up this. In my case, i am just using spacy to lemmatize a dataframe. So i dont need to use all the component that are in spacy like explain here : https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling.
I disabled all the components i don't need. But in French, to lemmatize, we need this components : "tagger", "parser", "lemmatizer".
So i convert this line self.nlp_spacy = spacy.load(spacy_model)
to this :
self.nlp_spacy = spacy.load(spacy_model, disable=["parser","tok2vec","ner"])
The treatment is about 2 to 4 times faster
